# Use Minix Filesystem on Ubuntu 13.04 (Kernel 3.8)

Tags: kernel, filesystem, minix

How can I add Minix filesystem support to Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) with Linux kernel 3.8? I have the Minix filesystem source code from an older version of Linux (2.0.39).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3.8 kernel *has* the minix filesystem source code.  You just have to enable it in the kernel config when you build your kernel.

```
make menuconfig
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain how to do that? :D

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I missed that (https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/minix?id=refs/tags/v3.8.13)! Can I add support without changing the kernel?

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson, like I said, you just have to *enable* it when you configure your kernel build ( `make menuconfig` ).